# PL/SQL trigger error bad variable using :new

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have two main tables Students and Classes with a relation many to many so i created a intermediary table. Every time i insert data on Students it populates with the number i generate on these two triggers: insert_Students_trigger and insert_Classes_trigger. Only the last trigger gives me an error of Bad bind variable new.Id_Class

Any ideia why ?

```
CREATE SEQUENCE id_Students_inc start with 1
increment by 1;

CREATE SEQUENCE id_Classes_inc start with 1
increment by 1;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER insert_Students_trigger BEFORE INSERT on Students
FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN

    :new.ID_Student := id_Student_inc.nextval;

  END;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER insert_Classes_trigger BEFORE INSERT on Classes 
FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN

    :new.ID_Classe := id_Class_inc.nextval;

  END;



CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Students_Classes_trig AFTER INSERT ON Students
FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN

    INSERT  INTO StudentsClasses (ID_Student, ID_Class)
    VALUES (:new.ID_Student,:new.ID_Class);
  end;
```

Comment: Trigger `Students_Classes_trig` is on `Students` table. It means that in the trigger you don't have an access to column `ID_Class`, this column is in `Classes` table.

Comment: You are completly rigth, thank you for help